# I made my header into div, made couple of divs inside of it. Two of them are social media logos, how do I make them clickable as urls?

Tags: html, css

I have a div for the header, and then I have 4 divs nested inside of it for:

- A Logo of the Brand
- The Menu
- Social Media Logo #1
- Social Media Logo #2

Now I'm trying to link the logo to the homepage, and the social media logos to the corresponding profiles.

The problem is that the image doesn't show up. When I delete the the image link from HTML code and put it inside of CSS of that div it does show the image but it's still not clickable.

HTML:

```
<a href="">
    <div id="fb">
        <img src="face.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#fb { 
    float:right; 
    width:90px; 
    height:90px; 
    margin:20px; 
}
```

EDIT: Sorry if I did anything wrong. Im new here and Im learning to code.
EDIT #2: Formating

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment as I've rarely used this account, but the html you have above should work as is. What is currently being shown in your browser window?

For future reference, these types of posts are well received here. You've not included specifically what the problem is, or what you've tried to fix it, or even what is being shown. Not trying to be rude, just speaking from experience.

Comment: The image doesn't pop up. It does pop up when I put it as background-image in css to this div but then it's not clickable.

Sorry about all the mistakes, new around here and thanks for answering!

EDIT: The div is there but it's empty and not clickable.

Comment: That sounds like a path error. Try including the complete path to the image in your HTML

Comment: The image is placed in the main folder. Now I've tried to create a new folder for it, edited the path, uploaded it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Honestly all aspects of your problem confuse me. Regardless of whether or not you use the background-image css property, the whole div should still be clickable. My only guess as to why the image is disappearing is that the CSS is moving it off screen. Otherwise it's probably a path error. Try playing around with this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRjdLe

Answer (score 0):

Look, we can make link on our page with this symbol # as I remember or we can just add name of our page. 
If you want to make clickable only image we can make it in this way

```
<a href="link to another page"><img src="pass to your image" /></a>
```

If you want to create button with image we can add properties to element a, code is above, width and height to our element a and make the image in the center of our "button" in real it will be a e

lement.
Or we can create element button and put inside of him image. And style button with height and width. Here is code

```
<button onclick="location.href='link to another website'"><img src="pass to image" /></button>
```

If your image didn't visible. It can be mistake in your path to your image from html file, try to use ../ to return to previous folder. Use developer tools in Chrome. And in tab Console you will see your error why is it didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a image that is also a link, wrap the image in an a tag this you can wrap in a div.

```
<div>
  <a href="your_link"><img src="your_image_path" alt="alt_name"></a>
</div>
```